# MONIT alarm by email and SMS

Tags: sms, alert, monit

I have MONIT setup to send alarm on email.

I have now a script which send SMS but don't know how to implement that into MONIT to also get SMS not just email.

Here is a string which I use in terminal to send SMS, how to implement that in MONIT to get also SMS alerts?

```
send-sms -u myusername -p mypassword mymobile0127466424 "Message on SMS - Monit Problem"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` and call your command/script for the use case.

For example, I would do something like below:

```
check process xyz with pidfile /var/run/xyz.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/xyz stop" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/xyz start"
  if does not exist then exec "/opt/somescript.sh"
```

Here if the process `"xyz"` does not exist then `somescript.sh` is called which can have code for sending sms or whatever else you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know I’m a bit late on this thread but last week I missed an important monit email alert and I then realized that sms would be the way to do it since I’m not always scanning my inbox for messages.

I found a quick way to do this using my mobile carriers email to sms gateway. Most cell phone carriers have an email to sms service; for example I use t-mobile so I can simply send an sms message from any smtp account by addressing the message to phonenumber@tmomail.net and the message is than sent to my phone as a standard sms. Here is a list of email to sms gateways for most carriers in the US https://www.lifewire.com/sms-gateway-from-email-to-sms-text-message-2495456

As an example my email settings in /etc/monit/monitrc looks like this 
`set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
username "email@gmail.com password "gmail_smtp_password"
using tlsv1
set alert my_cell_phone_number@tmomail.net with reminder on 5 cycle`

It doesn’t matter what smtp server you are using as long as it’s configured correctly in monit the sms alerts will work like a charm.